# Headline colors not diplayed correctly, emacs-calfw

Tags: org-mode, calendar, calfw

In [emacs-calfw](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw) some headlines are not displayed correctly (wrong color) as shown in the screenshot below. I created an [issue](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/152) where I described the problem in more detail and also explained how to reproduce this behavior.

Also, I would like to find out how to filter by TODO-items in emacs-calfw as raised [here](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/69#issuecomment-1374890807).

I would be really thankful for any help!

[image: headlines calfw]

Comment: The last commit by the author was 5 years ago.  I read a comment from the author, perhaps in response to an issue, that the library is complex even for him/her and that it would require immersing / studying the library again to make any revisions / fixes / testing.  I share that viewpoint in that I initially modified the library for my own use-case and implemented a few of my own bug fixes.  If you were to prepare a sample data set and steps 1, 2, 3, perhaps someone might tackle this project for you.  Absent a sample data set to work with and steps 1-2-3 to reproduce the issue, it's difficult.

Comment: The comment that I remembered reading was actually posted on reddit about 5 years ago:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6096u8/status_of_calfw/df5yg6w/ :  "*I'm calfw author. I use calfw everyday. I think it is not broken yet. Recently, I have little time to maintain my OSS projects. Because calfw is somewhat complicated to me, I could not switch the context in my head smoothly. I'm sorry for leaving many issues and PRs. If someone or a community would takeover calfw, I willing to step down and would contribute as one user.*"

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @lawlist! 
I already prepared a sample data set in this [issue](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/152) I created and mentioned above. I did not spell that out here to avoid duplication. Or do you mean something different by that?
  
And I am aware that calfw is not actively maintained anymore. I just find it really useful and would like to stick with it.

Comment: In the event that anyone is following this thread, I posted a suggested fix to the Github issue:  https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/152#issuecomment-1384701895

Comment: As to the second question about filtering out certain entries, `cfw:open-org-calendar` eventually triggers the function `org-agenda-get-day-entries`, which calls the applicable data gathering functions such as `org-agenda-get-scheduled`, `org-agenda-get-deadlines`, etc.  Those data gathering functions call `org-agenda-skip` ... Therefore, consider let-binding the applicable skip variables with the appropriate filter/skip when launching `cfw:open-org-calendar`.  See:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Agenda-Views.html

Comment: NOTE:  `cfw:org-agenda-schedule-args` has a default value of `nil`, in which case calfw will defer to `org-agenda-entry-types`.  This is a list.  The available elements of that list are as follows:  `:todo`, `:timestamp`, `:sexp`, `:scheduled`, `:scheduled*`, `:closed`, `:deadline`, and `:deadline*`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the hints! 

For other readers: Please see these issues for more information
https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/152
https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/issues/69.